# Problem using Gradle and Mapstruct and Lombok and Spring Boot (No implementation for mapper)

Tags: java, spring, gradle, lombok, mapstruct

I am using Gradle and Lombok and  Spring Boot and Mapstruct.
For some reason my mapper won't work.
It says, it cannot find an implementation for the mapper.

I already tried different approaches of adding Mapstruct to my Gradle build.
Maybe I am still importing it wrong?

When searching stack overflow I found several answers for similar situations, but none of them worked for me.

Anyways, here's my Code:

**Einheit.Java:**

```
package de.derandy.meinkochtopf.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "einheit")
public class Einheit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;

}
```

**EinheitDto.Java:**

```
package de.derandy.meinkochtopf.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EinheitDto {

    @Column
    private Long id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
}
```

**EinheitMapper.Java:**

```
package de.derandy.meinkochtopf.mapper;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.derandy.meinkochtopf.model.Einheit;
import de.derandy.meinkochtopf.model.EinheitDto;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@Component
public interface EinheitMapper {

    EinheitMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(EinheitMapper.class);
    
    
     Einheit einheitDtoToEinheit(EinheitDto dto);
     EinheitDto einheitToEinheitDto(Einheit einheit);

}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.diffplug.eclipse.apt" version "3.26.0"
}

group = 'de.derandy'
version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Spring boot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'  
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    // H2
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    // Test
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // Mapstruct
    compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final' 
}
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
server.error.include-message=always
spring.banner.location=banner.txt
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:199)
    at de.derandy.meinkochtopf.controller.EinheitControllerTest.testGetEinheits_fails(EinheitControllerTest.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at de.derandy.meinkochtopf.controller.EinheitController.getEinheiten(EinheitController.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for de.derandy.meinkochtopf.mapper.EinheitMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:61)
    at de.derandy.meinkochtopf.mapper.EinheitMapper.<clinit>(EinheitMapper.java:14)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for de.derandy.meinkochtopf.mapper.EinheitMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58)
    ... 93 more
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed my mapper like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface EinheitMapper {

    
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
    Einheit einheitDtoToEinheit(EinheitDto dto);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
    EinheitDto einheitToEinheitDto(Einheit einheit);

}
```

Now it works if I build it with gradle but it does not work in Spring tool suite

Answer (score 3):

In order to make Lombok and Mapstruct work together you will need the Lombok plugin.

The  Lombok plugin io.freefair.lombok plugin is required.

Here is my working configuration:

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.5.0-rc1"
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24"
    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24"
  
    compileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.1.Final"
    testCompileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.1.Final"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.1.Final"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct- processor:1.5.1.Final"
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the dependency order is so important to make the lombok and mapStruct work together is fine, here are my dependencies order

```
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"

    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as a workaround I migrated to maven and now it works.
Seems like somehow the gradle inside my Spring Tool Suite did not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing what properties you are willing to map in the EinheitMapper.Java
Also, @Column is not required there.

I am sure you want to do the Mapping of Dto to Entity class and vice versa.

If you want to save your time for the inverse mapping from entity to dto
You can use :

```
@InheritInverseConfiguration
```

So your mapper should look like this:

```
@Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
@Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
Einheit einheitDtoToEinheit(EinheitDto dto);

@InheritInverseConfiguration
@Mapping(target = "eventCategory", source = "eventCategory")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Siddharth, I applied your changes, but sadly it did not work :(

Comment: What error you are facing after these changes?
If possible you can follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVCrLp-k494&ab_channel=TechnoTownTechie

Comment: the problem was, that somehow the mapper was not properly loaded by Spring. I used the workaround of changing my project into a maven project and voilá the same code worked.

Comment: Oh.. good to hear that.